# What are the best places online where math educators can discuss their experience?

Tags: teaching, teacher-development

As a math teacher I often experiment new things (for instance non obvious ways to use technology in the classroom, or new ways to teach something), and I think it would be useful if I could share my results without having to write my own blog that few people would read. What are the most popular websites to do this?

Comment: Do you have a problem with this forum? Seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: @DanChristensen, Stack Exchange is for questions and answers, and not generally for discussions.

Comment: I wonder what happened to the math teacher forums that Dave Renfro used to be on several years ago.

Comment: @guest: The Math Forum discussion groups were closed (I don't know why) at the end of 2017, although the archives still exist. The teaching ones can be found [here](http://mathforum.org/kb/forumcategory.jspa?categoryID=14), and as a general rule the further back you go in the archives the better overall the discussions. On the whole, much better discussions can be found at Math Forum's [ap-calculus and ap-statistics archive](http://mathforum.org/kb/forumcategory.jspa?categoryID=21), but they tend to be mostly (but not always!) devoted to topics related to those subjects. **(continued)**

Comment: The late 1990s posts in [mathedu](http://mathforum.org/kb/forum.jspa?forumID=185) are especially recommended for discussions of post-calculus college mathematics.

Comment: There is also a bit of a blogosphere related to math education. Not that impressed with it in general. But certainly, if you want to express a view, blogging and asking for replies is one way to go. I really prefer forums but don't know of a good one. SE Q&A has a lot of limitations because of the stifling of discussion (I think opinions and debate are more worthwhile than canned answers). But what can ya do?

Answer (score 3):

For an absolute free-for-all with no restrictions on extended discussions (unlike here) or anything else for that matter, you could try sci.math at Google Groups.

WARNING: It is currently infested with cranks and trolls, but you can just ignore them. They can't block your postings. I wouldn't recommend it for students. The trolls there seem to delight in misinforming naive readers. Best not to engage them at all. Three of them are really quite insane. Don't give out any personal info, e.g. full name, place of work, school board, etc.

Yes, it has come to this, but if you can filter out all the noise, serious discussions are still possible there.

EDIT: You may also get some input from professional mathematicians at sci.math. I have found them very helpful over the years. I couldn't have developed my proof software without them.

Answer (score 3):

Many teachers use Twitter to share and discuss teaching. One large community includes teachers from early childhood to university level, mostly from North America but also from other countries. It calls itself the "Math(s) Twitter-Blog-o-Sphere" and uses the hashtag #MTBoS to identify tweets where they want to share or discuss their teaching ideas. You can see tweets with this hashtag without signing in to Twitter by searching for the hashtag. This link goes direct to the search ordered by most recent. https://twitter.com/search?f=tweets&vertical=default&q=%23MTBoS&src=savs

Comment: +: Some more with the hashtags **#iteachmath** [self-explanatory] as well as **#tmwyk** [talking math with your kids]

Answer (score 2):

The [Mathematics Teaching Community](https://mathematicsteachingcommunity.math.uga.edu/) would seem to be a good place, but unfortunately it seems to be unavailable.  (It has been unavailable for a few years now, I think.)

From the [University of Georgia](http://www.math.uga.edu/mathematics-education) website:

> The *Mathematics Teaching Community* is an online community for those of us who want mathematics teaching to be a vigorous, vibrant profession. It's a place where we can learn with and from each other and build a repository of knowledge about mathematics teaching. Everyone who teaches (or taught) mathematics at any level from PreK through college is invited. Use the tags to search for topics of interest. Post submissions, which can be anything for or about mathematics teaching, such as activities, questions, or links to useful resources. Vote for postings that you find helpful or interesting.

An article in the [Notices of the American Mathematical Society](http://www.ams.org/notices/201406/rnoti-p621.pdf) provides more information.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of Facebook groups that might be useful:

- If you are interested in discussing *research* in mathematics education (including "action research" in your own classroom, which sounds like what you are interested in), try the [Math Education Researchers](https://www.facebook.com/groups/mathedresearchers/) group (of which I am a moderator).
- If you want to discuss curriculum and best practices with other teachers, try the [Math Teachers Professional Learning Network](https://www.facebook.com/groups/113674342553157/) group.

Both of these are closed groups, meaning you must ask for permission to join.